# Alias in KNEX with Postgres db

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

The code in `knexjs` like below

```js
.select("resources.id")
```

will be translated to below SQL

```
SELECT "RESOURCES"."ID"
```

But PostgreSQL only recognized `RESOURCES.ID` , not`"RESOURCES"."ID"` as valid column

Is this a known issue? Is there any suggestion apart from using SQL raw?

Comment: `"RESOURCES"."ID"` is a different name than `"resources"."id"` you need to convince Knex to either get rid of the stupid double quotes or write everything in lowercase. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the wrapIdentifier to remove the quotes

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    wrapIdentifier: (value, origImpl, queryContext) => value});
```

http://knexjs.org/#Installation-wrap-identifier